# How can I log my output to .txt file instead of the terminal in Expo?

Tags: react-native, logging, expo

I am using Expo for my React Native Application.    `console.log(responseJson)` writes the App.js output to the my zsh terminal however my Json gets truncated with the following message.

> ...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)

I want to be able to view the entire Json by logging the output to a .txt file on my app directory.

Is there a solution or workaround without having to eject my Expo app to ExpoKit?

Comment: Did you look at logs in chrome dev tools console and terminal console?

Comment: @Oleg I am using Safari. No output is shown in the Safari console, I tried.

Comment: Open chrome and enable debug js in expo client menu, run expo start

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution:**

install json-server

```
npm install -g json-server
```

create a new file for logs:

```
echo '{"logs": []}'> logs.json
```

start json-server:

```
json-server logs.json
```

now in your code you can store:

```
let veryLargeTextWorks = "1234567890";
    for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      veryLargeTextWorks += veryLargeTextWorks;
    }
// veryLargeTextWorks.length == 20480
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/logs", {
      date: new Date(),
      msg: veryLargeTextWorks
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have different solution, you can view complete logs in ScrollView.

You need to save response JSON using useState and then write code like this in ScrollView.

```
return(<View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView>
    <Text>{ JSON.stringify(responseJson) }</Text>
    </ScrollView>
</View>)
```

I have checked this code. It will show complete logs without any problem.